# Can the LinkedIn API return a list of a user's saved articles?

Tags: linkedin-api

The LinkedIn docs for the [articles API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/articles-api) show that I can get a particular article's content etc. by doing a

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/originalArticles/{originalArticlesId}
```

But it's not clear to me where I get that `originalArticlesId` from. How do I list the articles that any given user has saved?

Comment: What does `GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/originalArticles` give?

Comment: I need this too. Did you find a way?

Comment: @CanÜrek, no, sadly not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LinkedIn API does not yet provide that functionality. The closest you can get to what you are looking for is to [get the articles published by a particular author](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/articles-api?context=linkedin/compliance/context#sample-request-2).

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/originalArticles?q=authors
```

I think that if you want to have this functionality you will have to do a scraping of the profile of the person who requires this functionality.

Comment: Is there any kind of documentation of it not being possible? or is it just a gap in the API?

Comment: Nowadays, It is a void gap in the API.

Comment: Is it still not possible? And is it possible to fetch a companies articles?